# Eclipse TFS plugin: import report from Excel

Tags: eclipse, tfs, import, export

Is it possible to export a report using the Eclipse TFS plugin?

From the work items I can run a report - all PBIs for example.  From here I'd like to be able to export the data into a local file (say Excel or CSV).  This can then be shared with others or worked on in offline mode.

This feature is supported from Visual Studio, but I cannot find it in Eclipse.

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

I'm using > Mac OS X 10.8 > Eclipse 4.2 with Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 with SP1 plugin

Update: I can copy/paste the data into Excel for a local copy, but I would like the ability to import any changes made - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a list of query results and then right-click on them to select Copy Selected Results or Copy All;  That will put the results to the clipboard and then you can paste them as a set of tab delimited results to a text file or you should be able to paste it into Excel as well.

See #2 in the following blog post:  http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs/five_hidden_fea.html

Comment: This works, but once the data has been consumed locally (and edited) I'd like to be able to save my changes - so an import feature would be required.  Do you know if this exists?

Comment: Now you're getting greedy, haha.  There's no such functionality in the 2010 version on Mac OS.  Let's cross our fingers for some expanded functionality :)